# C buffer conversion to int

Tags: c, buffer

this snippet

```
unsigned char len_byte[4+1];
...
for(i=0; i < 4; i++) {
   printf("%02x ", len_byte[i]);
}
```

prints

```
8a 00 00 00
```

I need now to set a integer value to 168 (0x000000a8).
Can sameone help me?

Thanks to all,
Riccardo

edit, I tried:

```
uint32_t len_dec=0; 
len_dec += (uint32_t)len_byte[0] | ((uint32_t)len_byte[1]<<8) | ((uint32_t)len_byte[2]<<16) | ((uint32_t)len_byte[3]<<24); 
printf("%" PRIu32 "\n",len_dec);
--> 4522130
```

Comment: Read your values as 16bits (short) with your loop stride equal to 2 bytes. In other words - set short pointer to the beginning of your array and increase it by one (will jump 2bytes at a time).

Comment: Is the input data *always* little-endian, and is it *always* 4 bytes long ? Also, you're "i tried" addendum is nice, but should also include *the result* of that effort. "it doesn't work" isn't much.

Comment: Then make sure you cast each `len_byte[n]` entry to `uint32_t` *prior* to each shift during the attempted assembly you have above. I.e. `((uint32_t)len_byte[1]) << 8`, etc...

Comment: @WhozCraig: edited post following your advice...

Comment: To convert 0x8a000000 to 0x000000a8, you'll need to shift all the bits; not just the bytes

Comment: @BLUEPIXY in what universe?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: thx, my mistake but the result is still diffent from 168

Comment: Can't you use `atoi()` for this? The `man` page should have some more details, but it seems like what you are looking for...

Comment: See my edited post. The code works well and is tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code, I got 168 as answer :

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned char len_byte[4] = {0x8a,0,0,0};
    unsigned int len_dec = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 3; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        len_dec |= ((len_byte[i] >> 4) << (8*i)) | ((len_byte[i] & 0xF) << ((8*i) + 4));
    }

    printf("%lu\n", len_dec);
    return 0;
}
```

[Tested here](http://ideone.com/E1HnpT)

The trick is to group each byte by 4 bits. 138 = 10001010 in binary. Grouping by 4 bits, you have 2 groups : `1000` and `1010`. Now you swap both groups : `10101000` which gives 168. You do this action for each byte starting at the last element of the array.

Comment: But he starts with '0x8a'.